# How to show notify top right corner few seconds on click glyphicon?

Tags: javascript, php, html, twitter-bootstrap-3, bootstrap-growl

I've implemented successfuly this Bootstrap notify tutorial with buttons:

[Tutorial](http://itsolutionstuff.com/post/bootstrap-notification-popup-box-example-using-bootstrap-growl-js-plugin-with-demoexample.html)

[Demo](http://demo.itsolutionstuff.com/demo/demo-bootstrap-notification-popup-box-example-using-bootstrap-growl-js-plugin-with-demoexample.html)

I would like to change a small thing, instead of a button, a glyphicon (from Font Awesome) on click it shows the success notify.

I was thinking doing that with an id on my code like :

```
<i class=\"fas fa-cart-arrow-down\" id=\"panier\">
```

Full code :

```
 echo "<h4 align=\"center\"> <a href=\"$softname?additem\"><i class=\"fas fa-cart-arrow-down\" id=\"panier\"></i> $a_photo_exp[0]</a></h4>";
```

I tryed modify JavaScript multiples times without success and now it is like that not working:

```
function myFunction() {
  document.getElementById("panier").bootstrapGrowl('Added to cart',{
        type: 'success',
        delay: 2000,
        });
}
```

My JavaScript is limited could you please explain me how to make it works please?

Comment: are you using jQuery ?

Comment: Yes i'm using jquery-3.3.1.js

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you need to use jQuery to open the notification, you can do something like this to make it work:

PHP code

Add a `event.preventDefault()` to block redirection after clicking the link.

```
 echo "<h4 align=\"center\"> <a href=\"$softname?additem\" onclick=\"event.preventDefault(); myFunction();\"><i class=\"fas fa-cart-arrow-down\" id=\"panier\"></i> $a_photo_exp[0]</a></h4>";
```

JS

```
function myFunction() {

  $.bootstrapGrowl('Added to cart',{
        type: 'success',
        delay: 2000,
  });
}
```

Comment: It works but it's not working with the redirection of href. I need href redirection for it adds item to his Cart. If it could do that also without the redirection block it would be perfect.

Comment: you can perform some ajax request to add item into the cart after clicking on the link.

Comment: I see. I don't have skills in Ajax. I think I have to call the JavaScript function to show the notify after item is successfully added after the redirection. I will try this night thank you.